# Highcharts - Continuous line with centered step (start before the first point)

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Using Highcharts, I'm trying to draw a serie with a "step centered". It works, but I really would like that my line start before my first point and goes through my last point.

Here are my options:

```
series: [{
                type: 'line',
            data: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9 , 10, 11, 12, 13],
            step: 'center',
            name: 'Center'
        }]
```

A [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3ggbqt33/1/).

And an illustration of what I want to do on the left:

[image: Start before the first point]

and on the right, at the end:

[image: End after the last one]

Comment: I think its not possible without dealing manualy with first and last property of svg path

Comment: I think you can achieve this chart with simple trick: http://jsfiddle.net/3ggbqt33/8/

Comment: That it @GrzegorzBlachliński! Thank you very much! It's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make similar chart by adding new point before your first point and adding last point after your last point:

```
  data: [5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13],
```

Then you can use xAxis.min and xAxis.max for showing only the range you want on your chart:

```
xAxis: {
  categories: ['', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', ''],
  min: 1,
  max: 9
},
```

Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/3ggbqt33/9/